# passing parameter Between forms (2 forms)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I Have 2 Forms (Form1,Form2)

When I pass parameter from Form1 to Form2 it will pass the ID not the value

Code in Form1

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal, Me.Combo5.Value
```

Code in Form2 (Load Event)

```
Me.Text0 = (Me.OpenArgs)
```

`Combo5` is the ID to retrieve other values from a table(ID ,  **username**,   password)

How can I retrieve the **username**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your datasource for the combobox has all three fields of the table you can access it via the Column property [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192660(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192660%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
    Me!Combo5.Column(1)
```

Otherwise you will have to do a DLookup() [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb148913(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb148913%28v=office.12%29.aspx)